# fullscreen IE javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I need what this...

```
$('#gatewayDimmer').width($('html').width());
$('#gatewayDimmer').height($('html').height());
$('#gatewayDimmer').css('display','block');
```

...is controlling to occupy the full screen/scrollable window. In FireFox, it does except for maybe...11px thats initially under the vertical scrollbar(when you use the horizontal scrollbar and scroll right, you can see the area under the vertical scrollbar was never occupied). In IE(7 at least), it occupies everything in the initial window, even the area underneath the vertical & horizontal scrollbars, but after scrolling down past the area the horizontal scrollbar would've covered, it doesn't occupy anything(it stops). I need every inch, pixel, etc. covered, from head to toe. To lock it, if you will. Is there something I can add, change here? Thanks in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow uses [Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), not BBCode.

Comment: @JCOC611, where would I put that?

Comment: `$('#gatewayDimmer').css({display:'block', position:'fixed'});`

Comment: @JCOC611 i could kiss you, thanks that did it!

Comment: I posted it as an answer. I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to have worked:

```
$('#gatewayDimmer').css({display:'block', position:'fixed'});
```